# should i be able to see network namespaces from my gke nodes?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Im exploring gke. I created a gke cluster through teh GCP GUI and when I hop on a node and run this command I see nothing:
`ip netns list`

I thought k8s used network namespaces for networking? how are those network namespaces visible?

Comment: Is this question still actual?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes networking builds on top of the Docker and Netfilter, and the thing that enables network namespaces for Pods is called Pause container.

> Pause container runs a very simple process that performs no function
>   but essentially sleeps forever, and is responsible for providing
>   network namespace that other containers can share.

Please read [here](https://www.ianlewis.org/en/almighty-pause-container) the article written by Ian Lewis explaining the role of Pause Container

Comment: I am on GKE and when I look at my pods for my app or even kube-system pods I see no "pause" containers

Comment: You should be able to see it on any worker node, with output of 'docker ps' command. Please give it a try:
docker ps --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Command}}" --filter status=running --no-trunc | grep pause

Answer (score 0):

Question is bit old, however since that time, has been created well described tutorial about `Network Fundamentals` [Learn Google Kubernetes Engine networking fundamentals with hands-on exercises](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/gke-networking-fundamentals).

There are 4 main Exercises:

- Exercise 1: `Introduction to network namespaces`

> introduces Linux virtual network devices. In this exercise, you configure devices, connect them, and configure the iptables rules that facilitate connectivity. This exercise also introduces techniques for interrogating the connection states.

- Exercise 2: `Introduction to GKE networking`

> explains the creation of a simple HTTP service in GKE. Using the techniques you learned in the previous exercise, you rerun captures.

- Exercise 3: `GCP load balancing and GKE`

> introduces the ingress controller as implemented by GKE, building on the load balancer service from the previous exercise.

- Exercise 4: `Visiting namespaces in GKE`

> demonstrates how to visit a pod's namespace directly.

In the `Exercise 1` you have information about `Network namespaces`. As stated there, as default there aren't any.

> For now, let's take a look at the configured network namespaces. There shouldn't be any:

`$ sudo ip netns list`

> Now, let's add a namespace called demo-ns and check to see that it's in the list of available namespaces:

```
$ sudo ip netns add demo-ns
$ sudo ip netns list
```

> A network namespace is a segregated network environment, complete with its own network stack.

For more details, please check [mentioned tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/gke-networking-fundamentals).